# Default App Engine version not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, version

I use the version in app engine to deploy multiple versions of my services. At this moment these are dev, load and live. I develop on my dev version and when I'm done I deploy to live.

When I access my endpoints I use **dev-dot-(myservice)-dot-(myapp).appspot.com**. This works without problems.

Now the strange thing: After I deploy to the live version (that has been set as default in the app engine dashboard), I can access my endpoint with **(myservice)-dot-(myapp).appspot.com**. But I can not access it via **live-dot-(myservice)-dot-(myapp).appspot.com**.

Why doesn't the live version work, while if I don't specify anything it takes the default version which is live.